# Windows Store App(.appx package)

Tags: windows

I developed windows store app(.appx) using windows 8.1 and VS Express for Windows,it works fine,i googled a lot on how to install in Windows 7...but no solution...

```
Is this really possible to install in windows 7...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is NO WAY to run a Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 App in Windows 7.

Actually, the features of a Windows Store App are not compatible with Windows 7 because of missing functions. For example, in Windows 7 there is no Charm Bar (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/charms-tutorial), so the code inside the Windows 8.1 app won't work.

You could think about deploying the .appx file to a virtual machine with Windows 8.1. You can find more instructions here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975356.aspx

If you need to develop a Desktop application for Windows 7 and you are familiar with Windows 8.1 app development, check out WPF applications development.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run W8 store apps on Windows 7. You need minimum Windows 8 to run these apps.